# Combine Rows of Multiindex DataFrame into Comma Separated Lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Given a multi-index DataFrame, I would like to combine repeated index pairs and list their values as comma-separated lists. For example, the input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Last Name' : ['Deere','Deere','Foo'   ,'Foo'  ,'Man'   ],
                   'First Name': ['John' ,'Jane' ,'Kung'  ,'Kung' ,'Karate'],
                   'Value1':     [ 1     , 2     , 3      , 4     , 5      ],
                   'Value2':     ['Green','Blue' ,'Yellow','Black','Purple']})

df.set_index(['Last Name','First Name'],inplace=True)
```

Provides:

```
                          Value1    Value2
Last Name   First Name      
Deere       John          1         Green
            Jane          2         Blue
Foo         Kung          3         Yellow
            Kung          4         Black
Man         Karate        5         Purple
```

I would like to convert this into the following DataFrame:

```
                          Value1    Value2
Last Name   First Name      
Deere       John          1         Green
            Jane          2         Blue
Foo         Kung          3,4       Yellow,Black
Man         Karate        5         Purple
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first convert column `Value1` to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html), then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by levels `Last Name` and `First Name` with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) `join`:

```
df['Value1'] = df['Value1'].astype(str)
result = df.groupby(level=['Last Name','First Name'], sort=False).agg( ','.join)
print result
                     Value1        Value2
Last Name First Name                     
Deere     John            1         Green
          Jane            2          Blue
Foo       Kung          3,4  Yellow,Black
Man       Karate          5        Purple
```